# pip + requirements and packages hosted on VCS server

Tags: python, pip

Hi all,

suppose I have two python packages (`packageA` and `packageB`) in two git repositories hosted on a private server; `packageB` depends on `packageA`, so `setup.py` in `packageB` contains:

```
install_requires=[packageA@git+ssh://my.git.server/packageA@master]
```

Then there's `packageC`, which uses both `packageA` and `packageB`. `packageC` is not an installable library, but a collection of scripts, so I have a `requirements.txt` which contains (among other pypi dependencies):

```
git+ssh://my.git.server/packageA.git#egg=packageA
git+ssh://my.git.server/packageB.git#egg=packageB
```

If I now try to install all requirements by `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 5) and packageA 0.1.0 (from git+ssh://****@my.git.server/packageA.git#egg=packageA) because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
The conflict is caused by:
    the user requested packageA 0.1.0 (from git+ssh://****@my.git.server/packageA.git#egg=packageA)
    packageB depends on packageA 0.1.0 (from git+ssh://****@my.git.server/packageA@master)
```

(Note: this is not a typo, the two versions requested are indeed the same.
`0.1.0` is the latest version for both packages, and it was set using the `version` keyword to `setuptools.setup`).

This started happening after I upgraded to pip version `20.3.1` from `20.2.4`.

Checking the full output log, I *think* the issue is due to the fact that, with the new pip version, `packageA` gets downloaded twice, first to install it and then as a dependency of packageB, and, by the end, pip does not understand these are the same package and does not know which one to choose.

I know that technically, in this case, a simple solution would be to simply remove packageA from `requirements.txt`, but this solution would not be feasible in a case where I have tens of packages.

What happened? What am I doing wrong and how should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be the best way to do it

git+git://github.com/path/to/package-two@master#egg=package-two

Comment: you mean in `install_requires` in `setup.py`? I tried that, but I get the same error. Moreover, isn't the usage of `git+git` discouraged? (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git)

Comment: I wasn't aware it was discouraged. It's strange how you're still getting that error with that in the requirements, hope you get this fixed soon.

Comment: Thank you very much anyway!